# How to install qemu patched version?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qemu

I followed the following steps to install qemu

```
# On Linux, you may need to install the SDL development libraries to get a graphical VGA window. On Debian/Ubuntu, this is the libsdl1.2-dev package.
# Configure the source code
Linux: ./configure --disable-kvm [--prefix=PFX] [--target-list="i386-softmmu x86_64-softmmu"]
OS X: ./configure --disable-kvm --disable-sdl [--prefix=PFX] [--target-list="i386-softmmu x86_64-softmmu"]
The prefix argument specifies where to install QEMU; without it QEMU will install to /usr/local by default. The target-list argument simply slims down the architectures QEMU will build support for.
# Run make && make install
```

But I get the following error :

```
cannot create regular file `PFX/bin': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not literally enter `PFX` on the command line.

The `PFX` token is actually a placeholder for the actual [path prefix](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/config.htm) passed to `configure` (usually either `/usr`, `/usr/local` or `/opt`, depending on where you want the package to be installed).